# AES S-Box: How is value for 01 mapped to 7c?

Tags: aes, finite-field, s-boxes

If irreducible polynomial $m(x) = x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1$ is chosen, or even for any other value, the multiplicative inverse will not exist for $01$, as $0000 0001$ will perfectly divide $m(x) = 100011011$ leaving remainder zero.

So then how it the value for $01$ mapped to $7c$ in AES S-box?

Comment: The inverse of $1$ is $1$ (in any ring).

Answer (score 1):

$00000001$ is its own inverse in the Rijndael field, because polynomial multiplication by itself gets $00000001$ and is unchanged by the modulo operation.  This will always be true in any ring, as noted in a comment above.

However, the specification of the Rijndael S-box is that after taking the inverse of the number in the Galois field, you have to multiply the result by a matrix then add (XOR) a constant: the ["affine transformation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_S-box#Forward_S-box).  That is what makes `0x01` map to `0x7C`.

Note that for the purposes of the Rijndael S-box, zero's inverse in the field is considered to be zero.  The affine transformation is applied to zero, getting the expected `0x63`.